# DRY up contexts-(related methods) Rspec matrix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, dry

I have some methods that are "related" in the same way as ActiveRecord's `valid?`, `invalid?`, and `errors`; and several `context`s in which I want to exercise/demonstrate them.

So clearly there's a matrix of `context` *vs* method returns.

A common pattern/practice is to nest `context`s within `describe '#<method>'` blocks, rather than the other way 'round, right? Rather than duplicate the `context`s within a `describe` for each method, I tried a single block for the 'set.'

But...`#errors` is more complex and deserves more attention than the others -- so it seems like it does deserve a `describe '#errors'` block

```
describe MyClass do
    ...
    describe '#valid? / #invalid? / #errors' do
        context 'all good' do
            ...
            it { should be_valid }
            it { should_not be_invalid }

            describe '#errors' do
                it { should be_an_instance_of( Hash )}
                it { should be_empty }
                it ...
                ...
            end
        end

        context 'some bad' do
            ...
            it { should_not be_valid }
            it { should be_invalid }

            describe '#errors' do
                it { should be_an_instance_of( Hash )}
                it ...
                its ...
                ...
            end
        end
    end
    ...
end
```

With more `context`s, the `describe '#errors'` and `it { should be_an_instance_of( Hash )}` begin to feel repetitive.

Is there a DRYer way to do this?
Is this "acceptably" un-DRY?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is that `describe` is for "things" and `context` is for "state" so yes, you've nested and used them appropriately, in my opinion.  As for your other questions, I don't know of a DRYer way to do what you've done and yes, I think what you've shown in acceptably DRY. If you had more commonality between your `#errors` cases, you could introduce a "shared example group", but that doesn't seem called for in this case.

All that said, I don't consider myself an expert on this subject and will look forward to any more informed opinions.